# Emails don't arrive to common inboxes

Tags: email, outlook, gmail, yahoo

I've just finished my application to sending emails from console and works fine, tests with our domain mailboxes shows the email arrives and passes all of the verifications.

Even the Mail-Tester service gives out a 10/10 https://www.mail-tester.com/web-rhb06
Also, the AppMailDev DKIM verifier gives a PASS to my DKIM signature, regard of SPF and DMARC records which are accordly setted.

Now the problem is getting the same result in common mailboxes as Gmail, Outlook and Yahoo, our first tests shows that our messages don't reach even the spam folder.

I don't know why because we got all of the requirements as SPF, DKIM and DMARC, and the ip nor the domain are listed on any blacklists.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have your mail servers reverse dns setup correctly.

Otherwise, if on unix using postfix, you can tail your log to see what gmail and the other mail servers are responding to your mail connection.

Comment: The smtp.log file says the following when the emails reachs the recipient's inbox: DeliveredRelay\1024+250 but in the gmail case, there's no reponse.

Comment: If there is no response from gmail, most probably an unsuccessful handshake between the two mail server. i.e mail will not be received, let alone even communicating. You might need to increase the verbosity of the logs to a higher lever so that it can show you the actual error. For a successful sending, you expect a status=sent and a dns 2.0.0 in your logs.

Comment: I tried to send a message from gmail to my server and the message arrived without problems

Comment: Yes gmail will send you a safe mail, try check what google sends you back when you try send it a mail.

Comment: Would be great if Gmail, Yahoo or Hotmails answers me with an error, but none of them sends any message back to my server, my MTA just keeps waiting and trying to resend but without success.